# MS Access SQL - Update field in one table with a count from another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table called 'FilesUploaded' which has a summary of all files uploaded to my access DB. I want to add a field in here that contains the count of all errors from another table.

- My FilesUploaded table contains a field called 'FileName' which has
  the full name of the file.
- I want to get a count of all records in table1 where the 'ValidityCheck' field contains 'Error'. Table1 also contains a field called 'Name_of_Report' which has the file name which will match back to the FilesUploaded table.
- The 'vFileName' variable will contain what is in both the 'Filename' field and the 'Name_of_Report' field

The below is the code I have tried using, but it says this type of join is not allowed and I have no idea what other way I can achieve this.

```
Call RunSQL("UPDATE FilesUploaded " & _
    "LEFT JOIN (SELECT table1.Name_of_Report, Sum(IIf([table1].[ValidityCheck] Like '*Error*',1,0)) AS ErrorCount FROM table1 GROUP BY table1.Name_of_Report) AS temp on temp.Name_of_Report = FilesUploaded.FileName " & _
    "SET " & _
    "FilesUploaded.[ErrorCount] = temp.ErrorCount " & _
    "WHERE FilesUploaded.[FileName] = '" & vFileName & "' ")
```

Does anybody know a different way can update the FilesUploaded table with a count of the ValidityCheck field from the Table1 table?

Comment: I haven't used ms access in awhile, but you might be able to use the [DSum](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dsum-function-08f8450e-3bf6-45e2-936f-386056e61a32) function to help get the count needed for the query. There is also a `DCount` function that might be a better fit, actually..

Comment: Thank you Paul T! I hadn;t even thought of doing it that way tried it there and it worked perfectly

Comment: Saving aggregate data is usually unnecessary and even bad design. If it can be calculated for input to a record then it can be calculated when needed.

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access, `UPDATE...JOIN` requires its analogous `SELECT...JOIN` to be [updateable](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html). Aggregate queries using `SUM` are not updateable queries. Therefore, consider [domain functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/expressions-684295d0-97c2-443c-8e0a-8c6b635bec56?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#id0eaabaaa=domain) like `DSum`.

Additionally, consider a stored query and call it in VBA with parameterization via [QueryDefs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/parameters-collection-dao). Do note the use of `ALIKE` to use `%` for wildcards in case you need to run query outside of the MS Access GUI such as in ODBC or OLEDB connections where `*` is not recognized.

**SQL** *(save as a stored query)*

```sql
PARAMETERS paramFileName TEXT;
UPDATE FilesUploaded f
SET f.[ErrorCount] = DSUM("*", "table1", 
                          "[ValidityCheck] ALIKE '%Error%' AND [Name_of_Report]='" & f.[FileName] & "'")
WHERE f.[FileName] = [paramFileName];
```

**VBA** *(run query without string concatenation)*

```vb
Dim qdef As QueryDef

Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedQuery")    

qdef![paramFileName] = vFileName     ' BIND PARAM VALUE
qdef.Execute                         ' RUN ACTION QUERY

Set qdef = Nothing
```